# How to get the URL of the current page in CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, csom

I have a SharePoint add-in that create a "button" on the page ribbon. When the user clicks on the button, it makes a call to a provider hosted app that resides in Azure. The request goes through, but I need to know the URL of the page where the button was clicked.  For example, the page where the icon is clicked is:

`https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/TDC/en-us/SitePages/Test4.aspx`

In my `AppManifest.xml`, I have the following:

```
<StartPage>https://yyy.azurewebsites.net?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPSource={Source}&amp;SPItemURL={ItemUrl}</StartPage>
```

In my `elements.xml`, I have the following:

```
<UrlAction Url="~remoteAppUrl/ContentExport.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPSource={Source}&amp;SPItemURL={ItemUrl}"></UrlAction>

<CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_ContentExportAction3ButtonRequest"
                      CommandAction="~remoteAppUrl/ContentExport.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPSource={Source}&amp;SPItemURL={ItemUrl}"/>
```

The `ItemUrl` does not get resolved, which I believe makes sense for a `StartPage`. The source gives me the following:

`SPSource='https://tdctranslations.sharepoint.com/sites/TDC/en-us/_layouts/15/commandui.ashx'`

Is it possible to get the URL of `Test4.aspx`?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this -

1. Get the current url of the SharePoint site.

   Asp.Net - `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Path`

   Javascript - `window.location.href`
2. Pass it to the app as a url parameter -

   ```
   <url>?RequestSource='<path>'
   ```
3. Decode it in the app

   ```
   Request.QueryString["RequestSource"];
   ```

Comment: How do I specify the javascript in the CommandAction as it needs to start with ~remoteAppUrl. CommandAction="javascript: .... does not work.

Comment: How are you redirecting the user on the button click, are you using href tag? or is it an aspx button?

Comment: aspx button.  Clicking on the icon in the ribbon causes an aspx page to be displayed.  The user then fills out the information and clicks on a button at the bottom of the page.  In the code behind for that aspx page, I need the URL of the page when the user clicked on the icon in the ribbon which is the itemUrl.  In my elements.xml file, how can I add in the Javascript to get the current URL and pass that into the CommandAction.